# Spring data JPA constraint issue

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have users in my application and users have work details, I use one method to set the user/work details data and then I either add a new user or modify an existing one.

This is the method for setting user/work data:

```
public WorkDetail setWorkerData(PatchWorkerRequest request, User user, WorkDetail workDetail) {

        if (request.getName() != null) {
            user.setName(request.getName());
        }

        if (request.getIdCode() != null) {
            user.setIdCode(request.getIdCode());
        }

        if (request.getEmail() != null) {
            user.setEmail(request.getEmail());
        }

        if (request.getPhone() != null) {
            user.setPhone(request.getPhone());
        }

        if (request.getAddress() != null) {
            user.setAddress(request.getAddress());
        }

        if (request.getSignatureLevel() != null) {
            user.setSignatureLevel(request.getSignatureLevel());
        }

        if (request.getAltContactRelation() != null) {
            user.setAltContactRelation(request.getAltContactRelation());
        }

        if (request.getAltContactPhone() != null) {
            user.setAltContactPhone(request.getAltContactPhone());
        }

        if (request.getRoles() != null) {
            user.setRoles(request.getRoles());
        }

        if (request.getStatus() != null) {
            user.setStatus(request.getStatus());
        }

        // Work details

        if (request.getJobRelation() != null) {
            workDetail.setJobRelation(request.getJobRelation());
        }

        if (request.getSalary() != null) {
            workDetail.setSalary(request.getSalary());
        }

        if (request.getDistricts() != null) {
            workDetail.setDistricts(request.getDistricts());
        }

        if (request.getCompetences() != null) {
            workDetail.setCompetences(request.getCompetences());
        }

        user = userRepository.save();
        workDetail.setUser(user);
        user.setWorkDetail(workDetail);

        return workDetailRepository.save(workDetail);
    }
```

Now, modifying an existing worker works fine with this code:

```
public WorkDetail modifyWorker(Long workerId, PatchWorkerRequest request) {
        WorkDetail workDetail = this.getWorkDetailById(workerId);
        User user = userService.getUserById(workDetail.getUser().getId());
        return setWorkerData(request, user, workDetail);
    }
```

But when I try to create a new user/worker I get an error that `"null value in column "user_id" violates not-null constraint"`. After checking the database using pgAdmin 4, I can see that the user was created but not connected to the WorkDetail.

This is the method for creating a new worker:

```
public WorkDetail createWorker(PatchWorkerRequest request) {
        WorkDetail workDetail = new WorkDetail();
        User user = new User();
        String generatedPassword = userService.generatePassword(8);
        user.setPassword(passwordEncoder.encode(generatedPassword));
        emailService.sendMail("SYDA", new String[]{request.getEmail()},
                "Project SYDA",
                "New password: " + generatedPassword + ".);
        return setWorkerData(request, user, workDetail);
    }
```

Entities:

User:

```
@Entity
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@TypeDefs({
        @TypeDef(name = "pgsql_enum", typeClass = PostgreSQLEnumType.class)
})
@Table(name = "user_acc")
public class User implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false, columnDefinition = "serial")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "id_code")
    private BigInteger idCode;

    @Column(name = "email", nullable = false)
    private String email;

    @Column(name = "address")
    private String address;

    @Column(name = "phone")
    private BigInteger phone;

    @Column(name = "alt_contact_relation")
    private String altContactRelation;

    @Column(name = "alt_contact_phone")
    private BigInteger altContactPhone;

    @Column(name = "password", nullable = false)
    @JsonIgnore
    private String password;

    @JsonIgnore
    @Column(name = "create_time", nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private Date createTime = new Date();

    @JsonIgnore
    @Column(name = "update_time", nullable = false)
    private Date updateTime = new Date();

    @Column(name = "status", nullable = false, columnDefinition = "active_status")
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Type(type = "pgsql_enum")
    private UserStatus status;

    @OneToOne
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
    @JsonIgnore
    private WorkDetail workDetail;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user")
    private List<UserFile> userFiles = new ArrayList<>();

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "signature_level_id")
    private SignatureLevel signatureLevel;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, targetEntity = UserRole.class)
    @JoinTable(name = "user_has_user_role",
            joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id")},
            inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "user_role_id", referencedColumnName = "id")}
    )
    private Set<UserRole> roles = new HashSet<>();

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, targetEntity = Mechanism.class)
    @JoinTable(name = "user_has_mechanism",
            joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id")},
            inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "mechanism_id", referencedColumnName = "id")}
    )
    private Set<Mechanism> mechanisms = new HashSet<>();

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, targetEntity = Service.class)
    @JoinTable(name = "user_has_service",
            joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id")},
            inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "service_id", referencedColumnName = "id")}
    )
    private Set<Service> services = new HashSet<>();

    @PreUpdate
    @PrePersist
    public void onCreateOnUpdate() {
        updateTime = new Date();
    }

    public enum UserStatus {
        active, temporarily_inactive, inactive
    }
}
```

WorkDetail:

```
@Entity
@Data
@Table(name = "work_detail")
public class WorkDetail {

    @Id
    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false, columnDefinition = "serial")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "salary")
    private float salary;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "workDetail",fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = true)
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
    private User user;

    @Column(name = "create_time", nullable = false, updatable = false)
    @JsonIgnore
    private Date createTime = new Date();

    @Column(name = "update_time", nullable = false)
    @JsonIgnore
    private Date updateTime = new Date();

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "workDetail")
    private List<UserLeave> userLeaves = new ArrayList<>();

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "job_relation_id")
    private JobRelation jobRelation;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, targetEntity = District.class)
    @JoinTable(name = "work_detail_has_district",
            joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "work_detail_id", referencedColumnName = "id")},
            inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "district_id", referencedColumnName = "id")}
    )
    private Set<District> districts = new HashSet<>();

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, targetEntity = Competence.class)
    @JoinTable(name = "work_detail_has_competence",
            joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "work_detail_id", referencedColumnName = "id")},
            inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "competence_id", referencedColumnName = "id")}
    )
    private Set<Competence> competences = new HashSet<>();

    @PreUpdate
    @PrePersist
    public void onCreateOnUpdate() {
        updateTime = new Date();
    }
}
```

Db tables:

```
-----------------------
-- User table
-----------------------

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS user_acc (
  id SERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  name text NOT NULL,
  id_code numeric NOT NULL,
  email text NOT NULL UNIQUE,
  address text NULL,
  alt_contact_relation text NULL,
  alt_contact_phone numeric NULL,
  signature_level_id integer NULL,
  username text NOT NULL,
  password text NOT NULL,
  create_time TIMESTAMP without TIME ZONE DEFAULT now() NOT NULL,
  update_time TIMESTAMP without TIME ZONE DEFAULT now() NOT NULL,
  status active_status NOT NULL DEFAULT 'active',
  CONSTRAINT FK_user_signature_level FOREIGN KEY (signature_level_id) REFERENCES signature_level (id)
  ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
);

-----------------------
-- User: work detail table
-----------------------

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS work_detail (
  id SERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  salary decimal NULL,
  job_relation_id integer NOT NULL,
  user_id integer NOT NULL,
  create_time TIMESTAMP without TIME ZONE DEFAULT now() NOT NULL,
  update_time TIMESTAMP without TIME ZONE DEFAULT now() NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT FK_work_detail_user FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES user_acc (id)
  ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT fk_work_details_job_relations1 FOREIGN KEY (job_relation_id)
    REFERENCES job_relation (id)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION);
```

Comment: You need to set `User` for your `WorkDetail` entity in order to save.

Comment: But I set it in the setWorkerData method

Comment: is it not null? did you debug it?

Comment: @Pijotrek it is null, but I am setting it. That's what I'm asking, why doesn't it set?

Comment: Try adding `cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST` to your `@OneToOne` user mapping in `WorkDetail` class maybe?

Comment: Tried PERSIST and ALL on both entities, same result.

Comment: It doesn't save the workDetail to the database at all, the user gets saved.

Comment: Am I correct to assume that `user = userRepository.save();` should actually be `user = userRepository.save(user);`? (I think that's a typo in your question)

Comment: Yeah, I actually changed that myself after posting, still the same problem though.

Comment: Anyway, I removed user_id from work_detail and added work_detail_id to user_acc table. Got it to work now.